# Scala, ZIO, Tapir - how to retrieve authorization token from header?

Tags: scala, zio, tapir

I have created tapir endpoint:

```scala
val getEndpoint = endpoint.get
  .securityIn(auth.bearer[String]())
  .in("players" / path[PlayerId]("playerId"))
  .in(query[PlayerRequest]("query"))
  .errorOut(someErrors)
```

Now, I would like to read all passed values: `bearer token`, `playerId` and `query`. So I created `ZIO` server logic:

```
PlayersEndpoint.getEndpoint.zServerLogic { case (playerId, query) => 
  //some logic to do...
}
```

It works fine, but whithout `bearer token`. Here I could not read `bearer token`. I tried to change it to something like:

```scala
    PlayersEndpoint.getEndpoint.zServerSecurityLogic{ case (token) => 
      //do smth with token 
     }.zServerLogic { case (playerId, query) => 
          //some logic to do...
        }
```

But it did not work. I would like to read all 3 values and decide about what to do after checking token. Docs and examples are very poor and do not show how to read tokens from tapir. Do you know how I should do it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```scala
import org.http4s.blaze.server.BlazeServerBuilder
import org.http4s.server.Router
import sttp.tapir.server.http4s.ztapir.ZHttp4sServerInterpreter
import sttp.tapir.ztapir._
import zio._
import zio.interop.catz._
import cats.implicits._


object TapirExample extends ZIOAppDefault {
  type Env = Any

  // fake type
  type PlayerId = Int
  type PlayerRequest = Long

  def authLogic(token: String): ZIO[Any, String, String] = {
    if (token != "secret") ZIO.fail("user not login")
    else ZIO.succeed(token)
  }

  val authEndpoint: ZPartialServerEndpoint[Any, String, String, Unit, String, Unit, Any] =
    endpoint
      .securityIn(auth.bearer[String]())
      .errorOut(stringBody)
      .zServerSecurityLogic(authLogic)

  val getEndpoint =
    authEndpoint
      .get
      .in("players" / path[PlayerId]("playerId"))
      .in(query[PlayerRequest]("query"))
      .out(stringBody)
      .serverLogic(token => queryTuple => getLogic(token, queryTuple._1, queryTuple._2))

  val getRoute =
    ZHttp4sServerInterpreter()
      .from(
        List(
          getEndpoint.widen[Env]
        )
      ).toRoutes

  def getLogic(token: String, playerId: PlayerId, request: PlayerRequest): ZIO[Any, Nothing, String] = {
    ZIO.succeed(
      s"""
        | token: $token
        | id: $playerId
        | request: $request
        |""".stripMargin)
  }

  override def run: ZIO[Any with ZIOAppArgs with Scope, Any, Any] = {


    val io = ZIO.runtime[Env].flatMap { _ =>
      for {
        _ <- ZIO.executor.flatMap(executor =>
          BlazeServerBuilder[ZIO[Env, Throwable, *]]
            .withExecutionContext(executor.asExecutionContext)
            .bindHttp(9090, "0.0.0.0")
            .withHttpApp(
              Router(
                "/" -> (
                  getRoute
                )
              ).orNotFound
            )
            .serve
            .compile
            .drain)
      } yield ()
    }

    io

  }
}
```

And the library version is

```scala
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "playground"
  )

val tapirVersion = "1.2.4"

val allDependency = Seq(
  "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-http4s-server-zio" % tapirVersion,
  "org.http4s" %% "http4s-blaze-server"      % "0.23.13",
)

libraryDependencies ++= allDependency

addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.13.2" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Test by curl

```bash
$ curl --location --request GET 'localhost:9090/players/233?query=334' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer wrongtoken'
user not login

$ curl --location --request GET 'localhost:9090/players/233?query=334' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer secret'

 token: secret
 id: 233
 request: 334
```

refer:

- https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/server/logic.html#re-usable-security-logic
- https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/blob/5332cf64d2ae912146e281e759b750d21bd1db55/examples/src/main/scala/sttp/tapir/examples/ZioPartialServerLogicHttp4s.scala#L22-L39

Comment: Thanks for answer. Have a question - what if in `authLogic` I dont want to return error if token is wrong or empty and just pass as it is and process is the same way as `else ZIO.succeed(token)`?

Comment: Of course, you can do that. But I'm afarid that it's not a good way to implement auth logic. In this way,  why don't you just pass auth token as parameter rather than use `securityIn` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IDE to give you the exact code but the idea is that the return of your `zServerSecurityLogic` can be used in the following `zServerLogic`.

Usually you'd validate the token in the `zServerSecurityLogic` and return some kind of `User` value that you can use as input in `zServerLogic`.

But you can also "do nothing" in the security logic and just passthrough the token so that it's available in the main logic.